# Will the title "senior researcher" hinder my career advancement for jobs with higher position?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, singapore

I am a PhD in CS and obtained an offer as ”senior researcher” in a global IT company in Singapore. Will the title hinder my career advancement for higher positions in other companies like becoming a vice president for a development team, and what will be a better title for good career advancement?

Comment: Yes, you're worrying over nothing if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Job titles are company specific and mean whatever the company wants them to mean. Employers are well aware of this, they're more interested in what you were doing and other relevant experience. So in the main it wouldn't be a hindrance.

Vice president is a bit of a joke job title in many industries, half a step above intern.

So if the experience you will earn is solid stuff, I wouldn't worry about the title.